# Adding support for IE8 to a pre-existing Protovis project

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, protovis

**Background Info**

I'm currently searching around for ways to add support for older versions of Internet Explorer for an existing project that uses Protovis (and therefore the  tag). My searching around has led me to two main places:

- http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/protovis-internet-explorer/

  - Touches on the Chrome Frame plugin as well as SVGweb
- https://gitorious.org/protovis/jloves-protovis

  - Seems to be an integration of Protovis with SVGweb

So far, I've downloaded the examples from each of these and opened them up in IE8 and have had no success whatsoever. The exact version of the IE is 8.0.7600.16385 and is running on a 64 bit Windows 7 Machine, and for the sake of SVGweb, the Flash version installed is 10.2.152.

**The question(s)**

Since I've had no luck making any of these work, I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone verify that the examples found in http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/media/upload/tutorials/protovis/protovis-ie.zip and/or https://gitorious.org/~jlove/protovis/jloves-protovis/commits/master work in IE8? If not, is there any other way (preferrably server side, but if there is a plugin that users can download and install for IE8 that would be okay too) to make protovis work on older IE versions?

Thank you for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had any luck with either of those solutions either. However, datamarket.com have recently come up with a drop-in shim available from http://blog.datamarket.com/2011/06/22/protovis-support-internet-explorer-8/ which worked right out of the box for me. The only drawback is that interactive aspects of your visualisation may not work in IE using the shim - I had some drag-select functionality that I had to re-implement with sliders under IE.

Comment: Thanks for your response fod. This does work for me too, though it is very limited. The lack of arc support is kind of crippling though, as one of the big eye-grabbers for our page is a sunburst visualization. Still, it's better than nothing.